# regexp - negate zeros in months and days R

Tags: r, regex, date, regex-negation

I have many vectors of dates from the USGS site.
Some of the dates look like this:
"1981-00-00", or like this: "1981-01-00".
I would like to find these impossible dates and just put "01" wherever I have "00".
This is what I did:

```
date <- c("1981-01-23","1981-00-02","2000-01-00","1900-00-00","1999-12-31")
month_regex <- "0?[1-9]|1[0-2]"
day_regex <- "0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|30|31"
tmp_date <- as.character(date)
tmp_month <- substr(tmp_date,6,7)
if (!all(grepl(month_regex,tmp_month))){
  substr(tmp_date[!grepl(month_regex,tmp_month)],6,7) <- "01"
}
tmp_day <- substr(tmp_date,9,10)
if (!all(grepl("0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|30|31",tmp_day))){
  substr(tmp_date[!grepl("0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|30|31",tmp_day)],9,10) <- "01"
}
print(tmp_date)
```

It seems to work but I want to know if it is possible to this in one or two lines with the replacement.
I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
  grepl(".+[-](?!00).+[-](?!00).+",tmp_date,perl = TRUE)
```

But wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: haven't read too carefully, but what's wrong with `gsub("-00","-01",date_string)` ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. I tried now: sapply(tmp_date,function(x) gsub("-01","-00",x))

Comment: @BenBolker I get a named vector where the names are the correct dates and the values are the original incorrect dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to replace `-00` anywhere it's found, a relatively simple `gsub("-00","-01",x)` should work:

```
date1 <- c("1981-01-23","1981-00-02","2000-01-00",
           "1900-00-00","1999-12-31")
date1.fix <- gsub("-00","-01",date1)
##[1] "1981-01-23" "1981-01-02" "2000-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1999-12-31"
```

If this does *not* work for you, or the results aren't what you wanted, you'll have to edit your question to clarify/give a reproducible example of what's not working ...